# How To catch global load event in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, wpf-controls

For each UI control on wpf, there is a 'loaded' event. Suppose I have a user control with a list of other controls, like Combobox. Now, If I catch loaded event for both "usercontrol" and for "Combobox", then the the loaded event is first occurred for Usercontrol and then for Combo box, which means when the user control is already loaded, its child elements may not be loaded completed. But, I want to catch the global load event, that means that load event will be occurred only when all controls are loaded successfully. How to achieve this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you tell us - what are you trying to achieve? If it's a templated control with the parts, which you're trying to acces using GetTemplatedChild, then Control Load only gets fired when all its parts get fully loaded.

Comment: I kind of agree with @Dmitry: you're probably trying to do something unorthodox here... please tell us the end goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no global `Loaded` event, you state that the 'loaded event is first occurred for Usercontrol and then for Combo box', this is probably due to the order in which you registered for these events. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Other events that might be of use to you are `LayoutUpdated`, this fires each time the visual tree is modified. You can register a handler, catch the first time this event is raised, then check your UI state to determine when your UI is initially rendered.

However, you normally only need to use these techniques if you are doing something quite complex or special within the UI, like creating a complex new control. For most applications you do not need to handle either of these events.

Comment: Say, I have 20-30 combo boxes and when they are loaded properly I will like to add some items to each of them. Now, if I do it on user control's load event, those combo boxes may not be accessible ( as they aren't loaded yet). I want an event that will trigger only when all controls inside the user control is loaded completely...

Comment: Why do you have to wait until they are loaded before adding items? you can add them directly or via binding before they have been rendered to the visual tree / screen.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that its ok to o all think only after user control loaded/initcomponent part. controls doesn't need to be rendered. Thanks.